# How to concatenate items from 2 lists into a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Trying to concatenate items from 2 lists and output them as a string. However, getting this error - can only concatenate str (not "list") to str

```
forenames = ['homer','bart','lisa']
surname = ['simpson']

fullnames =[]
for name in forenames:
    fullnames.append(name + ' ' + surname)
    

print (fullnames)
```

Comment: Regarding your problem, if I append an element to the surname list , will it produce 6 fullnames? Or?

Comment: How would I fix that issue if I were to append an element to the surname list?

Comment: `from itertools import product; [f'{first} {last}' for first, last in product(forenames, surname)]`

Comment: @James I was asking to clarify your use, would it be the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in the following way:

```
forenames = ['homer','bart','lisa']
surname = ['simpson']
for forename in forenames:
print(forename + ' ' + surname[0])
```

The output looks like this:

```
homer simpson
bart simpson
lisa simpson
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for something like this?

```
forenames = ['homer','bart','lisa']
surname = ['simpson']

fullnames =[]
for name in forenames:
    fullnames.append(name + ' ' + surname[0])
print ("\n".join(fullnames))
```

Output:

```
homer simpson
bart simpson
lisa simpson
```

Answer (score -1):

```
forenames = ['homer','bart','lisa']
surname = ['simpson']

for f in forenames:
    for s in surname:
        fullnames = [f'{f} {s}']
        str_fullnames = ''
        print(str_fullnames.join(fullnames))
```

OR

```
forenames = ['homer','bart','lisa']
surname = ['simpson']

for f in forenames:
    for s in surname:
        print(f,s)
```

Comment: What is the purpose of putting it into a list then `join`-ing, when the f-string itself already has the answer (the fullname)?